# Why wasn't the Russell paradox solved by creating a third kind of pertinence, say $\rlap {~\small+} \in$, beyond $\in$ and $\notin$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, advice, paradoxes

[I am trying to understand the historical process of math, and also the principles in a larger scope than just learning the axioms. So I think this question is a good exercise in that direction.]

I will put a computational analogy here just to avoid jumping straight to
$a \rlap {~\small+} \in A \iff a \in A, a \notin A$, and hopefully clarify my question.

Informally, if we allow $R = \{ x \mid x \not \in x \}$ to be understood as a process of building $R$ (or an algorithm in some sense), every set could be matched against the criterion sequentially, one at a time.
When it comes to $R$ itself, up to that moment it qualifies to be included.
After inclusion, it violates the criterion. So it should be removed.
At that point, the process stay indefinitely cycling between inclusion and removal.

If such process is allowed to be run in parallel, i.e., all sets are matched against the criterion at once, we promptly get the finished $R$, except for $R$ as an element of itself, whose presence is undecidable. If we accept this as part of the life, $R$ would "exist" in $R$ with ambivalence - it would be "semi-contained" by $R$.

Therefore, $\rlap {~\small+} \in$ would be given by:

$a \rlap {~\small+} \in A \iff a \in A, a \notin A$

I suppose problems emerge when redefining cardinality... or the implications for the generality of this.

Comment: What benefit does this give us? Now we have elements whose membership in sets is unknown? That takes away the very benefits of sets in the first place!

Comment: It's worth noting that if you encode Russel's paradox in type theory (where proofs are somehow programs that can actually be executed), you get a program that supposedly will yield a contradiction when it's run - which is bad because no program can ever actually construct a contradiction! What actually happens is that the program gets stuck in an infinite loop - sort of like you're describing here. I'm not aware of any similar attempts to patch such holes by adding a third state, though. People usually just try to make sure proofs/programs terminate by changing the axioms.

Comment: I believe the problem here is going to be that you are now restricted to computable set membership, which means that almost all the situations where $\in$ would apply, you are instead going to have to use the new relation. Remember that set membership even in the reals is not computable - it's undecidable in general whether two reals are equal - so I'd expect notions of decidability of a relation will be quite restrictive for you.

Comment: @DonThousand So the criteria for defining axioms is dependent on the advantages for an intended usage? I am asking because I really want to know. There is no straight/universal (global optimum in some sense) definition for sets?

Comment: @MiloBrandt Thanks for the food for thought :)

Comment: I think one could reasonably say there is no known global optimum for set theory - which is why people study alternative set theories like NF, or ZF, or NBG! Even if you accept ZFC as the one true set theory, there are still tons of different large cardinal axioms to add.

Comment: @PatrickStevens I'd like your point about "computable set membership". And also about computability on reals, I have enough to digest some time here, thanks!

Comment: Yes, Russel's paradox can be avoided using three-valued logic.  But so what?  See https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/lukasiewicz/